# Из данного массива получить список

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, list, dropdown

Скажите почему список не выводиться? Мне нужно из массива получить список и сделать из списка Dropdown.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  var contacts = ['Jenny Hess', 'Elliot Fu', 'Stevie Feliciano', 'Christian', 'Matt'];
  var ul = document.createElement('ul');
  for (elem in contacts) {
    var li = document.createElement("li");
    var a = document.createElement("a");
    $("a").appendTo("li");
    $("a").attr("href", contacts[elem]);
    $("a").text(elem);
    $("li").appendTo("ul");
  }
  $("ul").appendTo("body");
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
</head>

<body>
   
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Предложения подобные этому  $("a").appendTo("li"); не имеют смысла, так как в DOM нет элемента с тегом <a>.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Данные предложения

```
$("a").appendTo("li");
$("a").attr("href", contacts[elem]);
$("a").text(elem);
$("li").appendTo("ul");
```

не имеют смысла, так как в начале запуска функции документ еще не содержит  элементы с тегами `<a>` и `<li>`. Причем вы должны использовать не строковые литералы при указании элемента, к которому хотите подключить новый элемент, а имена переменных, которые ссылаются на вновь созданные элементы.

Скрипт может выглядеть следующим образом

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8"/>
    <title>Creating a List</title>
    <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script>
        $(function () {
            var contacts = ['Jenny Hess', 'Elliot Fu', 'Stevie Feliciano', 'Christian', 'Matt'];

            var ul = document.createElement("ul");

            for (var item in contacts) {
                var a = document.createElement("a");
                a.href = contacts[item];
                a.innerText = item;

                var li = document.createElement("li");
                li.appendChild(a);
                ul.appendChild(li);
            }

            document.body.appendChild(ul);
        });
    </script>
</head>

<body>
    <h1>Creating a List</h1>
</body>

</html>
```

И поместите скрипты в заголовок документа.